# How do I convert a Calendar object to an ISO 8601 format DateTime string?

Tags: freemarker

I'm trying to output the `datePublished` field in a [Google AMP schema object](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/article#article_types). For example:

```html
<script type="application/ld+json">
  {
      ...
      "datePublished": "2005-10-22T00:00Z",
      ...
  }
</script>
```

The `datePublished` field in my JCR app is rendering as a FreeMarker `Calendar` (e.g. `Oct 21, 2005 7:00:00 PM`) in the template.

How do I convert a data type of `Calendar` to an ISO 8601 format DateTime string (e.g. `2005-10-22T00:00Z`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the FreeMarker `string.iso_m_u` built-in. For example:

```html
<script type="application/ld+json">
  {
      ...
      "datePublished": "${publishDate!?string.iso_m_u}",
      ...
  }
</script>
```

Reference: [Built-ins for date/time/date-time values](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_builtins_date.html#ref_builtin_string_for_date)